# Movie Licensing

Tags: licensing

Not sure if this is the right place to ask, but here we go...

I am planning to create a VR game where the user will be able to watch movies. One of the issues I have thought about would be licensing for the movies, obviously I can't afford to pay huge licensing bills for a game that may not get any sort of revenue, and I want to have a large selection of movies.

I have thought that it could technically be used as a video player, but I want it to be more of a cinema simulator, where people can connect and have a virtual representation of themselves in the cinema, when a person connects they will viewing at the same point the movie is at. (as if you walk in to the cinema late and start watching)

I don't have much knowledge of this area so I was hoping one of you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Licences to include actual movies in your game would probably be prohibitive.

If you want to have a certain selection for a demo version of the game, you could use films that are in the public domain:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_in_the_public_domain_in_the_United_States

You won't find the new Star Trek there, but as a proof of concept for a game that you are not sure to ever be able to monetize, it could work.

Comment: Not just films in the public domain, but any movies that are provided under certain licenses, notably the Creative Commons BY license.

Comment: Makes absolute sense, thank you very much.